# SQLite for Windows Runtime is returning an "ReadOnly" error SQLiteException object

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime

SQLite for Windows Runtime is returning an "ReadOnly" error SQLiteException object while inserting a new record in my SQLite database.

I am not sure what's causing it but this "ReadOnly" error is what I got
[image]

I tried to update the database security and even lamely added "Everyone" to make sure but I still get that error. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using Sqlite-net? Synchronous or async api?

Comment: Yes I am using SQLite-Net and Synchronous API. One thing I didn't mention there was, I have an sqlite database added in my project with Build Action "Content" and copied always. I am accessing this database file from here "Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path". But when I changed it  to "Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path" and have the database created at runtime, I can insert new records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application files cannot be changed, hence the "Read-Only" error you are seeing. You are correct instead to copy the file to the LocalFolder, where the application will have full read-write access.

If you need to populate your db with data initially, you can do this either prior to adding the file to the project in Visual Studio, or after the db is in the LocalFolder.