# Desktop application deploy — attempt to write a readonly database sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, desktop-application

I have created a small Desktop [**WinForm**] data insertion application using C# VS2013 and SQLite database. It is working Fine and all the CURD Operation. But when I created Setup of this application using Advance Installer. Then whenever i run the application and try to Insert Data it popup this screen

[image: This is The Error I Got.]

And Thanks..

**Here is Some Code Snipt.**

```
//Add Property Function.
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=database/MyProperty.db;Version=3;Read Only=False";

    public static long AddPropertyToDatabae( Property property )
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection( ConnectionString );
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand
        {
            Connection = con,
            CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO Properties (PropertyName,PropertyAddress,PropertyCity,PropertyState,PropertyZip,PropertyNotes)" +
                " values (@Name,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip,@Notes)"
        };
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Name", property.PropertyName );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Address", property.PropertyAddress );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@City", property.PropertyCity );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@State", property.PropertyState );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Zip", property.PropertyZip );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Notes", property.PropertyNotes );

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Get the Last Inserted RowId.
        cmd.CommandText = "select last_insert_rowid()";
        long rowid = ( long )cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        con.Close();
        return rowid;
    }
```

**Note**

This is 100% workring code on the VS. but it only generates error when i Create Setup of the Application

Comment: inside your setup application are you doing any Create commands.. if this is an existing SqlLite file perhaps there is an issue with how you are trying to deploy it.. can you show use code.. also can you step through the installer code.. to see if you can pinpoint and or recreate the error..?

Comment: No. I am only using **INSERT** and **SELECT** Commands..

Comment: there must be something that you are doing in regards to the insert or Select Command can you show some of your code for those two CRUD Functions...?

Comment: I will show you in a mint...

Comment: I have added the Code Snippet to Question You can check..

Comment: few things.. 1st the Insert Command should be in a stored procedure, then after the insert command has been executed you want to create on the C# side Out parameter.. on the SQL side you want to return from the Select statement within the Insert stored procedure, `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` if you want to do this the current way without having to create a stored procedure then I will post example in the Answer section.. ok..

Comment: the code looks fine what about the code in the Installer.. is there anything that would cause  the code to execute when Installing..? Return value for newly inserted field should be cast as an `int` btw but I will post the example

Comment: To My Knowledge SQLite Does not allow Store Procedure.  And in creation of setup i just follow the simple steps.

Comment: Is there any solutions you have in mind. Bcz i tried many different solution but none of them worked.

Comment: my bad.. I forgot that you stated SQLite

Comment: I posted how you can get the last inserted record.. so you won't have to make multiple round trips to the DB but when you say you followed the steps I don't know what steps you followed.. can you elaborate..

Comment: I was talking about the http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ Steps to create .exe File.

Comment: so does it create a MSI..? can you uninstall the old one and recompile the code and re-Install.. what about deploying the application without using the installer.. also make sure that the dll's for the SQLite are actually being deployed.. set the property of that dll's CopyToLocal=true..

Comment: Yes it creates .EXE and .MSI. I have done that many time and try to create application from other laptop but didn't get any results..

Comment: so it runs fine when you run it locally without the installer..correct..? I wonder if this is a dll issue can you show what the using section in your .cs  file looks like at the top of the code behind.. also paste a screen shot of the references node too.. make sure also that you do not have any hard coded paths in the app.config file that do not match files paths on the remote or other laptop

Comment: Yes it runs fine locally.. and there no hard paths in the app.config file.

Comment: Hey Brother I got the solution of my Error. It was nothing but took my 7 hours :-(..
here is the link to the solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060446/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-is-returning-an-readonly-error-sqliteexception-obje

Comment: that sucks that it too `7` hours however very glad that you stuck it out and found a solution.. good job

Answer (score 2):

Technically error was not in the SQLite Database. But it was the Folder Error. I was Creating the Sub folder For the database file and it does not has the permission as the Local Output folder. So I just moved my database to Main **BIN** folder it Worked.:-)

Here is the Link where i found the solution.
[SQLite for Windows Runtime is returning an "ReadOnly" error SQLiteException object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060446/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-is-returning-an-readonly-error-sqliteexception-obje)

**-- Important --**

If you got problem like that please try to change the directory of your database file to main output directory..

Comment: I had the same underlying issue, but instead of moving the database file to a different folder, I was also able to get around it by running the executable that's trying to write to the database as Administrator

Comment: @JoeIrby you are right. I found this out later and now every time I have to use the DB like this. I always make the exe run as Administrator so the DB file has the proper read and write access.

Comment: @Awais can you please provide the new connection string

Comment: @priyankas you can do two things, 1: make your application Run as Administrator (Administrator Access) then you can put your db file anywhere in the project directory and it will worked perfectly. 2: just put the db file to BIN folder and use the connection string like this  " Data Source=YourDatabase.db;Version=3; ".

Answer (score 1):

> During creating windows installer setup file : set Application folder path: [WindowsVolume][ProductName]

I used Advanced Installer to create windows installer setup file.

[image]

If you try to set up path **[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]** then you are not able to write data in Sqlite but if you run the application in Run As Administrator mode then Sqlite readonly issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Sql Command to the following so that you do not have to run 2 separate sql commands there is no guarantee that you will get the correct last inserted row if 2 people hit that code and insert at the same time. I would need to see the installer code to see what could be happening there..

```
"INSERT INTO Properties (PropertyName,PropertyAddress,PropertyCity,PropertyState,PropertyZip,PropertyNotes)" +
  " values (@Name,@Address,@City,@State,@Zip,@Notes)SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
rowid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

(Maybe a little late...)

I just solved this problem.

An app can read and write its `LocalFolder` arbitrarily, so you just need to copy your data file to that folder.

The code is like:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("your-file-path"));
await file.CopyAsync(localFolder, "any name", NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

Then you can create SQLiteConnection in this way:

```
string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "abc.db");
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={dbpath}")
```