# How can I update an element of an existing XML file in c# Windows 8 App?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have an XML file located in Assets folder. I face no problem when tried to read the file using Linq. However, when I wanted to write to that file I see no error and the target element never gets updated.

My codes are below:

```
private static readonly string mealsXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets/meals.xml");
    private XDocument loadedData;
```

In the constructor I have initialisation code:

```
loadedData = XDocument.Load(mealsXMLPath);
```

The actual code that I am using to update existing element value is here

```
public async void UpdateQuantity(Dictionary<int, int> orderdetails)
        {
            XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(mealsXMLPath);
            foreach(var key in orderdetails.Keys)
            {
                XElement upd = (from order in xmlFile.Descendants("Meal")
                                where order.Element("ID").Value == key.ToString()
                                select order).Single();
                upd.Element("Avaibility").Value = (Convert.ToInt32(upd.Element("Avaibility").Value) - orderdetails[key]).ToString();


            }
        }
```

I have tried other built in methods such as `xdoc.save("path")` and `xml...Create(..)`.But none seems to be working in C# Windows 8 app.

Comment: InstalledLocation is read-only... related: [SQLite for Windows Runtime is returning an “ReadOnly” error SQLiteException object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060446/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-is-returning-an-readonly-error-sqliteexception-obje)

Comment: I am a beginner to Windows 8 app development. Can you please provide a solution which will enable me to achieve my goal.

Comment: Your xml probably has a namespace and that is why there is no updates.

Answer (score 0):

you have to save your document into a writable directory :

```
using (var stream = await (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(mealsXMLPath))).OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    xmlFile.Save(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
}
```

Comment: Error, Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7)

Comment: i now made a minor modification, the error is gone but the xml file never gets updated.

Comment: using (var stream = await (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(mealsXMLPath) , CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)).OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))