# Sqlite Xamarin Readonly exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm using SQLite in a Xamarin Forms application. I've got the declaration of a the SqlLite connection path as shown below

```csharp
public class AnrodidSqlite 
{  
    string GetPath()
    {
        try
        {
            var databaseName = "mydb";
            var sqliteFilename = $"{databaseName}.db3";
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }
            using (File.Create(path))
            {
                var connection= new SQLiteConnection(path);                    
                connection.CreateTable<Location>();                    
            }

            return path;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetAsyncConnection()
    {
        var path = GetPath();
        var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path,SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        return conn;
    }
}
```

with it being called in a dal layer here

```csharp
public class LocationDal
{   
    SQLiteAsyncConnection  _database; 
    
    public LocationDal(AnrodidSqlite sqlite) => 
        _database = sqlite.GetAsyncConnection();
    
    public async Task SaveLocation(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        try
        {
            var originCity = searchCriteria.OriginCity;
            await _database.InsertAsync(destinationCity);
        } 
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

the exception I get is a Readonly exception from Sqlite. The exception message is **SQLite.SQLite3+Result.ReadOnly**

Comment: How is `_database` instantiated in your second code clock

Comment: The AnrodidSqlite class is inserted as  a dependency in the constructor.  I've updated the code

Comment: Im asking how the `_database` object is instantiated, are you saying that you're talking about `_database` and it is of type AndroidSqlLite? EDIT: I saw your edit, I see what you mean now.

Comment: See if this question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060446/sqlite-for-windows-runtime-is-returning-an-readonly-error-sqliteexception-obje . Seems you need to store your db in your working dir in order to get ReadWrite access

Comment: Had a look but seems more like a windows 8 issue. cant figure out what's wrong on Anroid

Comment: Android only allows you to store in the working directory of  the app itself. You're storing it into the `Personal` directory of the device. You can probably only read from there. Every app gets a part of the device's disk called the working directory if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Every example i've seen says to use the Personal folder. So which option do you suggest i use

Comment: I might be wrong, and it could be the Personal folder. But since you clearly ask for ReadWrite access, the only other problem could be the filesystem of Android. If it's not  that, I don't think I can help you. Maybe you need to set a permission in the android manifest?

Comment: I switched from Async to Synchronous one and it  seems to be working

Comment: Well done, sorry I was of no help

Comment: Arshad, how did you do that?

Comment: I had an open connection on my db. I ensured i closed it all