# SQLite Error: Attempting To Write In A Read-Only Database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, readonly

Im making a simple application in C# using Visual Studio and WinForms.. I’m using SQLite as my database.. When I use the Run feature within Visual Studio, everything works 100% beautifully.. The problem arises when I install my program onto another computer.

When I install and run my program in another computer, at first, everything works great. Things that require select statements work perfectly.. However, when I try to do something that adds a row to a table or modifies an existing row, my program crashes with the following error: “Attempting to write on a Read-Only Database.”

Upon doing some research online, I realized that this error wasn’t 100% accurate. The database is read-write.. However, the folder containing the database is read-only. So I guess I have to move my database from this read-only folder, to a read-write folder somehow.. How do I go about doing this? Which folder is it in currently, which folder should I move it to, and how do I prevent this move from causing any errors?

This answer identifies the problem, but doesn’t give a clear solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068894/10216226

Please help me out! I’m at the final stretch of developing this application and I really would love to have this completed!

Thanks!

Comment: The duplicate you noticed answers the question; what don't you understand about it? Do you want us to write the code for you? Even if we wanted to, we can't because we don't know your database or connection string.

Comment: No I don’t want you to code it for me.. The response I shared explains the problem, but doesn’t go into detail on how to solve it.. Hence my questions: How do I go about doing this? What folder is it in and what folder should I move it to? How do I make it so that this move doesn’t cause other problems?